# Field next to one that is not "Visible by default" moves from the right column to the left

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a form in Dynamics CRM 2011 which has two columns. At the bottom of the left-hand column is a field which is initially not visible (the "Visible by default" checkbox is not checked). Under some circumstances I might want to make it visible using JScript.

The problem I'm having is that when it's not visible, the field to its right is moving left. I don't want that to happen, I want the other field to remain in the right-hand column.

Any suggestions for how to do this? I can't put a Spacer in as obviously there is a field in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative would be to add a new 2-column Tab to the form, each containing one single-column section.

You could do this just for the two fields, but of course it does mean that the one whose visibility you are controlling would be out of the normal tab order (ie not next after the column above it). This may be a non-issue for you. You can format the tab to not show it's label so it is in effect invisible.

Better would be to effectively replace your whole two-column section with such a two-column tab structure to retain the tab order you have now. If you want a section label, then both must have one to keep alignment correct. You may need to do some non-ideal options such as the right hand tab's section having a label of ".", or you may be able to choose a perfectly valid label for that column, separately from the left one.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on how your form is set up, but you can sometimes set up two sections, and show/hide them.

e.g.

```
Section 1
Field A | Field B

Section 2
Spacer | Field B
```

So to show just Field B, hide Section 1 and show Section 2.
To show them both, show Section 1 and hide Section 2.

Comment: Great idea! Of course, these sections don't have to have visible labels or lines, but will affect the "tab order" of the form compared to the fields being at the bottom of an existing multi-row section.

Comment: Just remembered - you don't need the spacer here, although it helps for clarity of intent

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll mark up both answers, but award the green tick to Adam's because it maintains the tab order :)

Comment: @StephenHolt agreed - a better solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to 'hide' the field. There is a difference between being not visible and being hidden.

If a field is not visible, it is removed from the screen while hiding fields is a css thing it stays on the screen and therefor the field to the right is not shifting to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest solution is to use Spacer.
Don't need to change your form if is already done, and not need to hide the field with JS, as it can looks a little bit ugly (showing a field and after hiding it)
http://crmdm.blogspot.ie/2011/04/how-to-insert-empty-space-between.html